# Regular expression from the alphabet {a, b} that finds strings wherer the numbers of a's is bigger than the number of b's

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expresion that finds strings where the numbers of lettes a's is bigger than the number of letter b's, I have tried to many expression but I cannot find a correct one, the output should be like this:

aab, babaa, abababa, aaaaaaab, aaabaabaa

I was trying using a lookahed but still cannot find a solution

```
^(?=(?:b*ab*a)*b*$)(?=(?:a*ba*b)*a*$)[ab]*$
```

Hope you can help me

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with regular expressions, as there's no way to do the necessary comparisons

Comment: Which regular expression language?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with regular expressions. The reason is that the regular expressions (often) use some form of a [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). No memory is used by the finite-state machine during its runtime to remember the states or transitions that were used (i.e. there is no computation history). For this reason, by design, the finite-state machine will not remember the number of `a` to be able in "some" way to compare to the number of `b`.

You need a machinery that works as at least [push-down automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton). This type of automaton is constructed usually on the basis of a formal context-free grammar. These grammars are able to express what you need.

For example, this grammar in ABNF syntax will suffice your task:

```
more  = equal "a" more / equal "a" equal / more "a" equal
equal = ["a" equal "b" equal / "b" equal "a" equal]
```

I took the idea from the grammar in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) "Distinct number of a's and b's".
What the grammar up does is actually simple:

- the `equal` rule accepts epsilon (the optional `[]` group)
- it also accepts the letter `a` equal number of `a/b` the letter `b` and again equal number of `a/b` (with other words: if there is `a`, somewhere after it there must be `b`)
- it also accepts the letter `b` equal number of `a/b` the letter `a` and equal number of `a/b` (with other words: if there is `b`, somewhere after it there must be `a`)
- generally rule `equal` will accept epsilon (nothing) or equal number of `a/b` regardless how they are distributed, but each first occurrence of one letter, ensures that its pair **will** follow eventually.
- then rule `more` (the start rule) has 3 alternatives:

1. accept equal number of `a/b` then one `a` (to ensure that the letter `a` are more, then again "more `a` letters then `b` letters")
2. accept equal number of `a/b`, then `a` (again to ensure that the `a` letters are more) and equal number of `a/b`. This alternative catches that the number of `a` are with one more then the number of `b`
3. more `a` letters, then `a` and equal number of `a/b`. This alternative catches that the input is in two pairs (as alternative 1) and in the middle of them is `a` (the pivot). The second of these pairs is with equal number of `a/b` and the first pair is with "more `a` then `b`".

That are all combinations possible. Clearly the grammar is non deterministic, and ambiguous. This is easy to prove with an input `a`: all of the 3 alternatives in `more` will accept it. The grammar is context-free, because the left hand side of each rule has only one non-terminal symbol, and the rules are referencing each other. It is not possible to translate this grammar to a regular grammar, because the rules reference each other and only a push-down automaton can use it for a recognition.